# Initiate event from Parent to Child component

Tags: reactjs

Have next situation - there is isolation component Timer: 
[image]
Which tick time from specified time to 0. And where time is over timer start up callback function. I have no problem with implement situation above but there is another situation. I need restart timer by some event from parent component - it can be everything (user click etc.). Soooo...how can i initiate this event from parent component?

In the same situation i used ref for Child Component and ruled Child component and Child state through ref. But i think it's bad practice. Sooo...Maybe someone have another sentence?

Code Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/52r3149rzn

Comment: Can you share the code that you tried

Comment: Using refs is not bad practice. If you do no want to use it, then take the function to parent (have it defined there) and simply pass its reference to the child. Now when parent event is raised, you can simply call it directly in parent component, and when event is raised in child component, you can simply invoke the same function through props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React you have 2 different way to have Parent communicating Child.

1. Setting props. This call some set of lifecycle and finally calls `Child.render()`
2. `ref` + calling some method. This `Child`'s method can do anything and once it called `this.setState` component will be re-rendered.

In your case using props to reset timer would be quite messy. Should it be boolean(`reset={true}`) or string(`current-time={'00:00'}`) or maybe number? How to track the case when we reset timer than it was running and we have reset it again(setting that prop to exactly same value like `reset={true}` does not make sense)? We need to check a lot in `componentDidUpdate` to ensure we differ a case when we are resetting timer and when we don't.

On the other side calling `timerRef.reset()` looks really clear and straightforward.

And no, using `ref` itself is not bad practice. [Uncontrolled components are](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)

Comment: using `ref`s itself is not a bad practice but using refs for anything that can be done declaratively is a bad practice as you can read in react docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs. The canonical way to solve this problem is to lift the state up so that the data is available for both parties that need it: button and time renderer.

Comment: @marzelin but it means you need also run timer on the parent's level too(something like `setTimeout(() => setState({timer} => {timer: timer - 1}), 1000)`). It means encapsulation leakage, does not it?

Comment: OP timer implementation does two things: provides counting logic and renders the timer. This is the root of the problem because it restricts places from where a component can be controlled (only the timer level or deeper). If you decouple logic from rendering and lift the logic higher, you are free to control the component and render its state whenever you want. One-way data flow is an artificial constraint imposed in react to make reasoning about apps easier. Components that use a given state can only be lower, never higher. Using refs like that breaks this and we are back in 2-way mess.

Comment: @marzelin I agree with you that having composition from 2 components say`<TimerEngine>` and `<TimerView currentValue={...}>` would be more flexible. But anyway _running_, _stopping_ and _resetting_ would be either in that `<TimerEngine>`(and we still have to call it somehow) or it will be duplicated in every parent component where we want to place timer

Comment: `TimerEngine` can have methods to control its state that are passed to its children but never to its parents. In react there is this explicitness that makes it easy to reason about. I can look at component definition and see what it needs (through props) and what it provides (what it passes to its children). Calling methods on `ref`s is implicit and disrupts this explicitness - virtually any component can depend on and call component's methods. Ideally `<TimerEngine>` should only provide *controls* and *data* to its children and leave it to them where and how to use it.

Comment: @marzelin I totally agree with you. In general. But reactjs does not provide any wrapping for `input.focus()` through `props` besides it could(just an example of imperative operation really hard to make in declarative way). Sometimes `ref` rocks and all other approaches would be overcomplicated

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to modify the state of a child component. This is not how react works. React is one way - from top to bottom.

If you need to share some piece of data between some components, move that piece of data to the nearest common parent in the tree. If a state is needed in many different nodes of the react tree, most notably when there are intermediate components that only pass the piece of information, use context or a dedicated state container like redux.

Here's timer implementation using context:

`Timer` provides time information and functionality for all its children descendants.

Current time can be obtained with `Time` component and reset functionality with `ResetTime`.

This solution is very composable. You can have timer functionality anywhere in your app through these two simple components.

```js
import Timer, { Time, ResetTime } from "./Timer";

function App() {
  return (
    <Timer>
      <div className="App">
        <Time>{time => <p>{time}</p>}</Time>
        <ResetTime>{reset => <button onClick={reset}>reset</button>}</ResetTime>
      </div>
    </Timer>
  );
}
```

```js
import React from "react";

const TimerContext = React.createContext();

export default class Timer extends React.Component {
  reset = () => {
    this.stop();
    this.start();
  };
  stop = () => {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
  start = () => {
    this.setState(({time}) => ({time: 15}))
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(({ time }) => {
        if (time > 0) {
          return { time: time - 1 };
        } else {
          this.stop();
        }
      });
    }, 1000);
  };
  state = {
    time: 15,
    reset: this.reset
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.start();
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
   this.stop();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <TimerContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </TimerContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export const TimerConsumer = TimerContext.Consumer;

export const Time = ({children}) => <TimerConsumer>
  {({time}) => children(time)}
</TimerConsumer>

export const ResetTime = ({children}) => <TimerConsumer>
{({reset}) => children(reset)}
</TimerConsumer>
```

Comment: Take a look in example. I want restart timer by clicking button from parent component.